# Netcat issues. Can't see output

Tags: php, netcat

Well, I have simple PHP that echoes ok. It is on port 9292, it is index.php
When I put http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9292/ on browser I can see "OK" message.
So I want to recieve it's output from netcat.

```
nc xx.xxx.xxx.xx 9292
```

it stacks. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post the code you tried?

Comment: Well yes, netcat doesn't send a HTTP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to verbose the connection, with

```
nc -v xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 9292
```

Then, when you'll get the 'connected' answer, type

```
get http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.php
```

and you'll get the html output, in plain text.